# loop through a dynamic form and panel and check if radio buttons check or not

Tags: c#, windows

I have a form that is dynamically created, on this form are several radio buttons that are created at runtime. There is a button on this form eg "Next" when the user clicks on the next I want to loop through and check if one of the radio buttons are checked before I continue, I have tried the following:

```
    void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in _form.Controls)
        {
            if (c is RadioButton)
            {
                RadioButton radio = c as RadioButton;

                if (radio is RadioButton)
                {
                    if (radio.Checked == true)
                    {
                        //code continue to next 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You must select at least one.");
                    }
                }

            }
        } 
    }
```

Kind regards
geo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to make it simpler

```
bool checked = _form.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(rb => rb.Checked);
```

**--EDIT--**

I updated the answer to recursively search all controls.

```
bool IsChecked(Control parent)
{
    if (parent.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(rb => rb.Checked)) return true;

    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        if (IsChecked(c)) return true;

    return false;
}

bool checked = IsChecked(_form);
```

Comment: hi LB - iim sorry I tried your suggestion it did not return any successful check items even after having checked a radio button.

Comment: LB - can sort of see where you coming from but even in debugging is still does not seem to pick up if radio controls are checked or not ie even after radio has been checked...odd(??)

Comment: LB wait yep got it to work now ! Excellent thank you - nice piece of code using LINQ like that :D

Answer (score 0):

If one of the radio is checked you should exit the loop so add an exit condition if one is found.

```
 if (radio.Checked == true)
 {
      return;
 }
 else
 {
      MessageBox.Show("You must select at least one.");
 }
```

For finding nested controls you should use:

```
 _form.Controls.Find()
```

Comment: ioden hi nope that doesnt work soz - might it be becuase the radio button are nested inside a panel? And I did mention these radio buttons are dynamically created (?).

Comment: try using Controls.Find() method

Comment: ionden - I might have explained it wrog my apologies - the radiobuttons are created inside a dynamically created form that dynamically creates ALL the controls (button, panels, radiobuttons etc)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your radio button is lying inside a panel. And hence the radio button is listed in the controls collection of the panel and not the form. Try this instead:

```
    private static void CheckRadioButton(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c is RadioButton)
            {
                if (((RadioButton)c).Checked == true)
                {
                    //code continue to next 
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You must select at least one.");
                    return; //should be
                }
            }
            else if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
                CheckRadioButton(c);
        }
    }
```

Now call this method by passing the `form` as the argument. Like this or so:

```
void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckRadioButton(this); //or whichever form it is..
}
```

You need not unnecessarily have an inner loop again confirming if the control is a radio button.

Comment: nawfal isnt ther a cast or something missing on radio.checked == true ?  cuz: error 'radio' does not exist

Comment: @geoNeo_ u r absolutely correct. I just missed it. Will edit now