# Loop through dynamic radio buttons if it check status Y/N

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I need advice...

I have form, that contains number of generated panels with usercontrol (usercontrol contains radio buttons generated at runtime).
http://tinypic.com/r/vq4kds/8 (structure of winform)

I saw this thread: [loop through a dynamic form and panel and check if radio buttons check or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823044/loop-through-a-dynamic-form-and-panel-and-check-if-radio-buttons-check-or-not)

Values are assigned from MySQL database, so I need to check this radio buttons against database. Also names of radios are assigned by loop:
From:

```
"radioButton1_"+[i].ToString();
```

To:

```
"radioButton4_"+[i].ToString();
```

**For example:**
I will have 10 groups of 4 radiobuttons. (40 radios) Should I save their states into array?
like this [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,...]. I need chance to check it against database.

I appreciate some simple solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to loop over the panels in the winform.  For each panel, get the usercontrol.  Then, loop over each control in the usercontrol.  If the control is a RadioButton, then check it against the database.  I'm not sure how you are matching the radio buttons to the database, but perhaps the Text attribute of the RadioButton matches up.

**Psuedocode:**

```
foreach Control panel in winform.Controls:
    // Type check
    if panel is Panel:
        // Get the user control from the panel
        UserControl usrCtrl = panel.usercontrol as UserControl
        foreach Control control in usrCtrl.Controls:
            // Type check
            if control is RadioButton:
                // do database stuff
```

**Edit:**
I would suggest setting the Tag attribute of your RadioButtons when assigning values from the database.  The Tag attribute can hold anything you want it to.  For example, you might set Tag to `YourTableName.YourColumnName`.  This way you can keep track of what field the RadioButton corresponds to.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I said that values are assigned from database, but thats not completely true. Because of problem with multiline radio, I used classic label as description of radiobutton. So I can check only states (1/0).

Comment: this `UserControl usrCtrl = panel.usercontrol as UserControl` has right syntax?

Comment: It is pseudocode.  The syntax might not be correct, but the intent should be clear.  Since you haven't posted much code I can't be more specific than this.